# Why is Chrome DevTools not showing me the stylesheet rules belong to?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

This is only happening on the site I am working on. If I inspect any other site, I see the stylesheet a rule is coming from to the right of the rule. As you can see in the screenshot below this is not the case for me here. I am using SCSS and compiling to CSS with CodeKit, but the end result is a flat CSS file so I'm not sure if that should have any impact.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How is the stylesheet attached to your page? If it is loaded via an XHR and then set as a `textContent` of a new `<style>` element inserted into your `<head>` (without the `//#sourceURL` comment), then this result is expected. Otherwise, please provide more info or (ideally), a publicly accessible URL where this issue occurs.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. I had added prefixfree.js to simplify testing and this is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know another source of DevTools problems :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was caused by [prefixfree.js](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/).